# Process Data in Google Storage on an AWS EMR Cluster in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, amazon-emr

How can I process data stored in Google Storage on an AWS EMR cluster in Spark?

Assuming I have some data stored at `gs://my-buckey/my-parquet-data`, how can I read it in from my EMR cluster without having to copy the data to s3 beforehand or download to local storage?

Answer (score 1):

First obtain Google [HMAC credentials](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/hmackeys) with access to the GS bucket/objects you want to process

Then use the S3A filesystem (already bundled with AWS hadoop distributions) with the following hadoop configuration values:

```
val conf = spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
conf.set("fs.s3a.access.key", "<hmac key>")
conf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "<hmac secret>")
conf.setBoolean("fs.s3a.path.style.access", true)
conf.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "storage.googleapis.com")
conf.setInt("fs.s3a.list.version", 1)
```

Then you can access google storage with `s3a` paths as follows:

```
spark.read.parquet("s3a://<google storage bucket name>/<path>)
```

Comment: never knew you could do that. Nice. I was just going to suggest "get the GCS JAR into the cluster and use gs:// links instead"

Comment: As far as I could tell the official hadoop connector for GCS doesn't support using HMAC credentials, you seem to need service account credentials. Seems like they want you to just use the S3 compatible API when you are using HMAC creds. But maybe you can make more sense of this documentation than me: https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/blob/master/gcs/CONFIGURATION.md